# Connect and delete folders in SVN repository

Tags: svn, repository, directory

I have administration access to a Subversion (SVN) repository.

The URL to the repository looks like: `http://svn.domain.com/svn/project/`

I've installed SlikSVN (command-line client) and I want to connect to this remote repository and delete some folders inside of it.

How can I complete this task?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless you want to permanently remove a folder from the repository (i.e. with its whole history), you can execute the following command:

```
svn delete http://svn.domaine.com/svn/project/FolderFoo -m "Deleted 'FolderFoo'"
```

See [`svn delete`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.delete.html) command-line reference for further details.

Answer (score 1):

Any command-line SVN-client (your is [Slik SVN](http://www.sliksvn.com/en/home/), BTW) work the same way:

Run the command `svn help rm` to see help pages on `svn rm` command.

`svn rm <URL>` is what you seek in your case.